# Command Line Parser With Multiple Command Types

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-core, command-line, command-line-parser

I'm creating a console app in .NET Core 5 which knows a set of commands.
The name of the application is `Strict.exe`. These are the commands I need to parse.

```
strict.exe load mytext
strict.exe read
strict.exe explode
strict.exe stich 3 4 5 6
strict.exe case -pascal
strict.exe join -l "pqr"
strict.exe echo "Making C# array"
strict.exe implode -d ","
strict.exe join -r "abc"
```

To parse the commands I'm using CommandLineParser library - https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline.
Now the issue is some of my commands are context aware. Like the first command `load mytext`

So if the text file is in same directory, It can be

```
load mytext
```

In case it is in a different directory, command can be

```
load "c:\Sample Data\mytext.txt"
```

Another issue is with Stich command. It can accept any number of arbitary values after 'stich'. Like

```
stich 1
stich 1 2
stich 1 2 3
```

Another case is command validation. If user is using a `join` command. It should be followed by a flag like '`-l`' or '`-r`' then a `string`. How can I enforce it.

I was able to parse normal commands using the library but I was not able to use it for my use case. How to create the Options class to cope up with the above requirements.

My current implementation can only parse 1st command

```
public class Options
    {
        [Option("load", Required = false, HelpText = "Loads a text file")]
        public bool load { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I've never used the library you reference, but I've used ManyConsole which if I recall supports all the different cases you mention. You may want to take a look at it

Comment: Can you share a link to the repo or documentation

Comment: https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole

Comment: Did you have a look at [verbs](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Verbs)?

Comment: I've looked into verbs. It satisfies much of my requirements but not all I've explained above